# String was not recognized as valid date time c# error

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have below code which is converting many other string formats in a valid datetime format.

```
  try
  {
  outputDate = DateTime.Parse(inputDateTime);
  }
  catch
  {
  outputDate = DateTime.Parse(inputDateTime, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
  }
```

However for below two cases it always failing

GetValidDateTimeFromString error for **13-10-2018 05:00:27**-> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at O365InventoryApp.InventoryDataUtility.GetValidDateTimeFromString(String inputDateTime, TextWriter log)

GetValidDateTimeFromString error for **14-10-2018 00:57:21**-> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at O365InventoryApp.InventoryDataUtility.GetValidDateTimeFromString(String inputDateTime, TextWriter log)

Note the highlighted two dates which are throwing exception while converting.I think it's a 24 hour format problem.So I also tried to convert like below

```
log.WriteLine("GetValidDateTimeFromString error for " + inputDateTime + "-> " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                    DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
                    string[] format = new string[] { "dd-MM-yyyy h:m:s tt", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" };

                    DateTime dt;
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDateTime, format, provider, style, out dt))
                    {
                        log.WriteLine("updated date -" + dt);
                        outputDate = dt;
                    }
```

Anyone can enlighten me what's happening here?

Comment: You're much better off using `[Try]ParseExact` instead of `Parse` because .NET doesn't have to figure out which format you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think DateTime.Parse doesn't accep the format you are providing, try this:

```
outputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be as mentioned in [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1185383/Cultureinfo-and-error-equals-string-was-not-recogn):

Windows 10 added new support for Jalali calendar, as a result:

the `DateTimeFormatInfo` Class `System.Globalization` class should return different date format strings when called on Windows 10 and older versions.

and example would be (taking Persian Calendar as an example):

```
String[] dateParts = s.Split('-');
int year = int.Parse(dateParts[0]);
int month = int.Parse(dateParts[1]);
int day = int.Parse(dateParts[2]);
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime dt = pc.ToDateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Quoted:

> The first approach coming into mind is using DateTime.Parse with the
>   fixed format "yyyy/MM/dd". But this will fail for specific dates. So
>   you have to split the string into the year, month, and day parts.

Try splitting your strings and see if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and i removed tt from end of format. That works for me:

```
var inputDateTime = "13-10-2018 05:00:27";
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite;
            string[] format = new string[] { "dd-MM-yyyy h:m:s", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" }; // i removed tt from first format of formats array.
            DateTime dt;
            DateTime outputDate;
            DateTime.ParseExact(inputDateTime, format[0], provider);// and i used first index of formats array
```